# Generate faces from multiple vectors / existing mesh

Tags: three.js

is it possible to automatically generate faces from list of vectors ? I have complicated mesh object and i want one of his sides to be automatically generated/closed.

Imagine that you have house but only side walls are defined and you want to automatically generate roof and floor from side parameters.

Object is already generated so I have to do it from existing mesh.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with ShapeGeometry, i did extract one side of "house" from vertices and new THREE.Shape and new THREE.ShapeGeometry did the rest.